# Expression needed for Two or more Matches

Tags: regex

I have some text:

```
cat is playing with the toy 
and the dog is chewing the bone

the bird is chirping 
the cat is watching the bird
```

I would like to create an expression to match only if `'cat'` is present in the text two or more times.

I have the following expression that works with one match but I want it to only work if there are two or more. Can someone assist?

```
^(?=.*\cat\b).*$
```

Comment: What is the scope? You say multiline, but how many lines should a regex cover?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this,

```
.*?\bcat\b.*?\bcat\b.*
```

Comment: or `.*?\bcat\b(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?\bcat\b.*`

Comment: I like to keep it simple, `(?:.*?\bcat\b){2}.*`

Comment: mine seems to be simple :-) cat...cat

Comment: multiline can be solved by passing `m` modifier. this allows `.` to match `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

using .* stops at every \n, therefore you have to account for the endlines.

Try:

```
    [\s*.*]*cat\b(\s+.+)*cat\b(\s*.*)*
```